# Ec2 cpu usage reached 100% frequently

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-ec2, magento-1.9, amazon-rds

I have a Magento 1.9 website and hosted it on Amazon server. I have m3.large ec2 instance and using RDS with db.m3.large instance.

My 2-CPU usage reached 100% very frequently and I need to restart my server again. For a while, it works fine but after few minutes it reaches 100%. Because of 100% usage of CPU my website goes slow and not able to open it easily.

What do I have to do?

htop screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an auto scaling. Auto Scaling helps you maintain application availability and allows you to dynamically scale your Amazon EC2 capacity up or down automatically according to conditions you define.

Please read more about auto scaling [here](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/)

To distribute the load  attach auto scaling group to an Elastic load balancer (ELB), which looks like below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Think you'd better login ec2 instance by **SSH**.
Then using top to watch  which process take much **CPU**.

You can also using **accton** command to turn process account on.
Then using **sa** command and **lastcomm** to display the details.

For Example:

```
sa --percentages --separate-times
```

Find the performance issue and try to solve it, and hope its helpful to you